# Importing a python module from another directory that contains other imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming I have this structure below :

[image]

**main1.py** :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')

from projectB import main2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2.main()
```

**main2.py** :

```
import module2
def main():
    print("test1")
    module2.print_2() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**module2.py**:

```
def print_2():
    print("test2")
```

When executing main1.py I get this error below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projectA/main1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from projectB import main2
  File "/projectA/../projectB/main2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import module2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: `import .module2` should work

Comment: Have a look at "relative import"

Comment: @12944qwerty Thank you for your answer but what if I don't want to edit what's in projectB. How can I edit projectA only to make this work

Comment: The error is in ProjectB not in projectA. It won't work unless you change projectB

Comment: I belive this post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3